# R: identification of spikes over an increasing-decreasing vector

Tags: r, vector

I am working on some electrical signal data in R and I need to find a method to automatically identify spikes based on their amplitude (let's say only >20 volts in the example below). In the figure below the vector data (red line) and the spikes (S1, S2, S3, S4, etc., I respresented only first 4) that I need to identify
[image: data and spikes]
I thought there would be some function/package but I googled and searched here and could find nothing

Here is the vector data in case you need it:

```
c(85.0278243029226, 107.785630550336, 129.604712826402, 149.260196364201, 
165.54556968829, 178.052163144247, 186.314871531986, 190.618957693203, 
191.017073538503, 189.129803259661, 184.73408895552, 179.5663413562, 
176.589072700205, 178.567376311842, 179.93688460071, 178.092196482404, 
177.404316433181, 177.302577227515, 177.678262879313, 178.597396688752, 
179.266976436512, 178.252503694388, 176.041787332138, 173.377001606721, 
171.139070346545, 168.900510540427, 166.71790158684, 164.987690133427, 
163.940112750076, 163.304640937595, 162.606852251293, 162.095954538859, 
162.010743413239, 162.291572181651, 162.959117935656, 164.828093867046, 
166.631270461545, 168.523766299647, 170.025625714026, 169.961180818194, 
168.966667150296, 167.450030382658, 165.735279091636, 164.358062119477, 
163.780855873138, 164.087794790775, 164.124232346191, 163.167850107202, 
161.566891027602, 159.587705093687, 157.079763655803, 153.284715147799, 
148.886663281258, 144.468085548619, 139.801518273117, 135.318492151769, 
131.36736142681, 128.211913398136, 126.000631512198, 123.841459571288, 
122.093178346309, 120.76808611823, 120.68879955721, 121.707488148399, 
123.345181065382, 124.531581736014, 125.30826497504, 125.679416571285, 
125.730431526173, 125.83775552009, 125.956717028583, 126.320862321528, 
126.903297727481, 127.65378493549, 128.045629034945, 127.917305390316, 
127.586826586707, 127.401931249429, 127.731203602501, 128.516687892614, 
129.334808015348, 130.460955844659, 131.694637251268, 132.996405786355, 
133.720548134535, 133.843173037137, 133.67166931588, 132.715430811475, 
131.844172655607, 131.266013713573, 130.972206713847, 130.524605288754, 
130.43709482893, 130.692537634409, 131.254651770889, 131.804421584906, 
132.02809936967, 132.240038185208, 132.608624182532, 132.650110138479, 
132.221085951647, 131.288731956601, 129.819219229094, 127.845939922511, 
125.930297894063, 124.405916063473, 123.288336175997, 122.78817900727, 
122.564190764832, 122.88753760754, 123.602948063603, 124.777196767208, 
125.998429570162, 126.602796107323, 126.970019022747, 127.068879656946, 
126.524864578463, 125.639882445874, 124.953283594761, 124.389239724224, 
124.293809245915, 124.659585744762, 125.196079164719, 125.756134255453, 
126.403566173903, 126.817132401542, 127.54723650003, 128.670147087747, 
129.567229836695, 130.192448109279, 130.939789083953, 131.211355386822, 
130.731690531078, 129.717713379868, 128.39596805898, 127.126990741187, 
125.688594982077, 123.561289495035, 121.300287007032, 119.005487632526, 
117.021878275914, 115.14337400117, 113.402992933639, 111.863408553786, 
110.782504618658, 109.687312236355, 109.427563401095, 110.169808472109, 
111.753445374089, 113.576973781928, 115.518734922863, 117.425570451335, 
119.479939213191, 121.395421504303, 123.181049109855, 124.971970348161, 
126.577785505098, 127.527105565498, 127.989983137464, 127.932388429442, 
128.086502802363, 128.526234173237, 128.887790749787, 129.254638422725, 
130.080632414976, 130.784985367532, 131.197735057203, 131.583081427029, 
132.161292192614, 132.606850692934, 133.033441021425, 133.143292751474, 
133.546876303784, 133.783226719973, 133.424972599721, 132.388702820632, 
131.478690332253, 131.140459952819, 130.99837470512, 130.788043118226, 
130.69527875847, 130.947692293638, 130.831259144621, 130.54975011419, 
130.08416695953, 129.1266471173, 128.152603117794, 126.804491496186, 
125.213785118192, 123.810515322982, 122.454307512909, 120.498881215305, 
118.398457835597, 116.752318442928, 115.252633382233, 114.174909115334, 
113.805214521771, 113.991207106124, 115.017595847238, 116.281507772996, 
117.324715846379, 118.086169818317, 118.722232141994, 119.184925042855, 
119.240831799154, 119.011196896175, 118.573533469824, 118.021184063881, 
116.735488266618, 115.228442950567, 113.734624451214, 112.705634720274, 
112.277279123878, 111.898158555131, 111.844979144836, 112.474583955334, 
113.249235145868, 113.822771248785, 114.506616122047, 115.46054903731, 
116.519878576841, 117.623761355882, 118.323202463285, 118.398229444417, 
117.803193586003, 117.002152665603, 116.399840273412, 115.903097687715, 
115.940928428259, 116.189290494538, 116.538782468981, 117.218046041496, 
118.18455755993, 119.388015906026, 120.443851203431, 121.387181441538, 
122.264658939348, 123.05012170259, 123.708208261462, 124.22431568087, 
125.137377644512, 125.967279199111, 126.658885095088, 127.152643387984, 
127.509436195882, 128.368102131731, 129.844669428728, 131.72940070825, 
133.741377913196, 135.775765708546, 137.382590564935, 138.753801163936, 
140.197934903518, 141.712222931547, 144.117585809248, 146.72024753215, 
149.185915321911, 151.288004890031, 153.327487654025, 155.561376376331, 
158.20445211803, 160.952413373961, 163.436039410405, 165.542272046775, 
167.375703266649, 169.278662614932, 171.598459071542, 173.680794162061, 
175.961375602524, 178.350051200209, 180.792970063358, 183.437752338887, 
185.834427399206, 188.216020710077, 190.443630399856, 192.18438600055, 
193.363447899707, 193.969231728223, 194.240756385249, 194.303895600588, 
194.32851497907, 194.817372012919, 195.741598222395, 196.126159694347, 
196.354783575954, 196.414292885815, 196.506974512743, 196.096157243958, 
195.229504946451, 194.405145362802, 193.25211841391, 191.87299040802, 
189.997491243623, 187.633187460031, 184.537067595231, 180.682644494953, 
176.262832035591, 172.610890232299, 169.749233952912, 167.307127199836, 
164.293346993164, 159.896614359481, 154.373826108445, 147.712276668112, 
140.316475547168, 133.351128854924, 127.998464101282, 125.784218041518, 
127.143854298661, 131.879337481802, 139.786801921627, 149.49064551596, 
160.126045074245, 170.376050544628, 179.543105995396, 187.418287899067, 
193.658272788341, 197.728361281727, 198.706986463758, 196.828198578129, 
191.037131821182, 182.32135233458, 172.107751790764, 162.271980289417, 
154.013275104376, 147.649810976225, 143.377653689278, 140.365470802228, 
138.830738662922, 137.727633290877, 135.413276727224, 131.874313552897, 
127.602249617123, 123.252736201788, 118.762335434429, 114.524481662391, 
110.192401003796, 106.637803582078, 104.713310441552, 103.769394743487, 
103.620797020843, 103.888607782129, 104.429012923645, 104.757494972944, 
105.139440537796, 105.705037534997, 106.243296351825, 106.685355257856, 
107.087685662546, 107.522275550398, 108.595598856486, 109.292053080986, 
108.865172564254, 107.636461242495, 106.348972438509, 104.228195031513, 
100.778795677427, 97.1120081679548, 93.4382568608119, 88.8694501458896, 
82.8382750130259, 76.4840025363609, 69.8861371249803, 63.6481996098672, 
58.7935902478825, 55.9393561713734, 55.3324256581366, 55.0246840235786, 
55.2823491157648, 55.9931196122378, 57.1685163117382, 59.1415941384165, 
61.790508133032, 63.517059158594, 64.3940856668447, 65.8535046240324, 
67.6396913156324, 68.4862132267192, 67.406046761564, 65.4586320710592, 
62.1168208583856, 57.9612560493921, 54.6586540708114, 52.956387483675, 
51.1951873525581, 48.6133380299079, 46.4796518622395, 45.629819423621, 
45.9379881887019, 47.1527921308174, 49.148541170277, 52.6487598458863, 
57.2503397333622, 61.562605557439, 65.0512336090039, 66.9953758282162, 
68.0933259391815, 69.0845495209384, 68.4662956156328, 66.2854691578942, 
64.4803694281894, 63.7668567329249, 64.1999855771059, 66.0764710118089, 
68.7384810283067, 72.4808944022655, 77.7634787015138, 84.0224143412208, 
90.731406769738, 96.7430248854119, 102.211849408634, 107.262345504672, 
111.634410257242, 114.937401084408, 117.160127033261, 118.441226762966, 
119.289744611567, 120.319664576315, 121.486687505711, 123.138280838076, 
124.317735121687, 125.506952706443, 127.093625961213, 128.019649057191, 
126.957075580488, 124.426788992598, 122.052340281469, 118.222716201035, 
113.143604649284, 107.771457153139, 102.042662013074, 96.80179223291, 
92.7799905853472, 88.7925005131795, 84.9560026008456, 80.6353147082328, 
76.8207490985649, 73.2417738012678, 70.1110859838866, 67.7145940148176, 
65.4205461032896, 62.9651666854718, 60.6529327486774, 59.3694399789337, 
58.9752226682343, 58.5271707372106, 57.8640200007509, 56.2778132009255, 
54.6649399386324, 54.2855441311599, 54.0918291929302, 53.3663649035699, 
54.0288225349698, 55.3505341737744, 56.2922900915149, 58.0051371411091, 
59.9766542857633, 62.5906893542514, 65.8338177362977, 70.5158697210584, 
76.4424039270741, 81.4658435620956, 86.3017011601784, 91.5779826430929, 
97.795499723262, 104.300826522228, 109.251940169704, 112.219414389583, 
113.703132530511, 115.744300828082, 117.497920061476, 117.766093071745, 
117.237647928725, 115.494574024816, 114.371123072872, 115.075099267571, 
115.64351891796, 115.504978908395, 116.01578457008, 116.965746492345, 
117.096187067756, 116.727678300633, 115.331476347846, 113.07136451129, 
110.230955780172, 107.31831038244, 103.760355091268, 99.1113838457074, 
94.2337424191086, 89.6056183736045, 86.5223133057085, 84.1042106366129, 
80.9112753300726, 77.0771145502476, 73.809036213072, 70.8838697532913, 
67.0915980719277, 63.3193547849687, 59.9155265055594, 55.3585211050333, 
49.9980233968981, 44.7807201452983, 39.408917627203, 34.1731145609945, 
30.6349844862471, 27.3820236225935, 23.7174303385913, 21.1318694416216, 
19.9454179791818, 20.2595565872978, 20.8337080706967, 21.9894637090075, 
24.9683536618811, 28.824328018789, 32.1623150467807, 35.0823748018498, 
38.6934445680426, 42.7632168431958, 46.527537478577, 50.0834243415966, 
53.9604439500715, 56.7585843207459, 58.9294478997089, 61.9062149140512, 
65.0207162655262, 67.3678109869824, 69.7032254517925, 71.5059938310432, 
72.7363370680266, 74.5147934097481, 77.0503659353132, 78.0785848043727, 
77.43762353232, 76.9176686602934, 76.4346059228449, 76.2931301768471, 
75.426169893548, 75.0722888985619, 76.2817024713461, 77.9100669127817, 
79.6404848865906, 81.2682106581132, 82.7669941050991, 84.5100768755416, 
86.2174705550458, 88.0949343177878, 89.5924039378162, 89.6659359245104, 
88.7326875809397, 86.9017940814523, 84.3179438882689, 81.5970693470447, 
79.0373181366286, 76.053948294668, 73.5997163676211, 72.5160191302188, 
72.6169205182349, 73.4295663458593, 74.3312781781158, 75.8459763666565, 
77.9911169576516, 79.9223748555848, 81.5718651212051, 83.0338315895842, 
84.9456288307489, 87.2258161564412, 89.5544679488251, 92.5358635520993, 
96.1504901527777, 99.5609320930982, 103.744704701418, 110.492747379003, 
117.936334219989, 122.986299463172, 125.154481576414, 124.363262863187, 
119.634506843345, 110.641195670973, 98.5702911769826, 84.7762625138948, 
71.2148708011502, 59.8751988951695, 51.538452870335, 46.8514158189711, 
46.683925993994, 51.0778846705728, 60.0751873525682, 72.2984122240058, 
87.1569299973791, 103.825420236132, 120.781879920269, 136.145400138653, 
148.137057041383, 156.681878082473, 161.167231996911, 161.357693766023, 
159.036699145051, 156.874528488442, 153.902672577687, 149.386684915604, 
145.748112492138, 143.711024917647, 142.678703916858, 142.049415926445, 
142.141990542364, 142.986376102273, 144.481618878735, 147.035391884705, 
149.94954662454, 153.445633785261, 157.390108827311, 161.361795919249, 
165.558639314756, 169.816841127828, 173.721588872235, 177.307548333364, 
180.079717635809, 182.250922742932, 183.681146308568, 184.642566276003, 
185.725898760298, 187.067267495286, 187.753716066699, 188.274019721323, 
188.343623650541, 187.727953829537, 187.119320436556, 179.509690520334, 
180.213404351591, 184.954964367281, 190.892851359267, 195.822589157033, 
197.908201415417, 196.051314084885, 189.615726824748, 178.617912473856, 
163.217198347046, 144.315648444576, 122.77488343998, 99.7413445105195
)
```

Comment: Can you articulate more precisely what constitutes a spike? It looks like a rule could be "highest local maxima is at least 20V higher than the lowest local minima within 50 time units"? I recall seeing many questions about identifying local peaks/maxima/max/spikes, but I'm not sure if this is a unique variation. The first approach that occurs to me would be to use `slider` or `zoo` to mark the local minima and maxima (ie is value larger/smaller than neighbors on both sides), then track the min/max of those within a rolling window, and then your spikes are the largest such min/max gaps.

Comment: You could look at `tsmp` pkg.

Comment: @Chris it appears to my uninformed eye that `tsmp` is capable of many things, you likely need to be more specific.